# Camera source for shootPhotoDistanceInterval (DJIWaypoint) on drones with multiple cameras

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

We are trying to add support for drones with multiple cameras like Matrice210 V2, Matrice 210 RTK V2.

In our app, we use the DJIWaypointMission object for flying missions and set the shootPhotoDistanceInterval property for capturing photos. What I am unable to figure out is

Which camera is the drone going to use to capture photos for drones with multiple cameras?
and if there is any way to set which camera to use for capturing photos while executing a waypoint mission.
Here is how I am setting the shootPhotoDistanceInterval and preparing a waypoint (Simplified version)

```
 let singleWaypoint: DJIWaypoint = DJIWaypoint(
                coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                    latitude: point[1], longitude: point[0]
                )
            )
if let distanceBasedTrigger = waypointProperties.dist_based_trigger {
                singleWaypoint.shootPhotoDistanceInterval = distanceBasedTrigger
            }
```

DJI Mobile SDK Version: 4.11.2
DJIWidget: 1.6.2

Thanks a lot for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a reply from DJI on the same. So it's not possible to set the camera for waypoint actions in `DJIWaypointMissionV1`. However, it seems like the same can be achieved using [`DJIWaypointMissionV2`](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Missions/DJIWaypointV2Mission.html) using the `actuatorIndex` param of [`DJIWaypointV2Actuator`](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Missions/DJIWaypointV2Action_DJIWaypointV2Actuator.html?search=actuator&i=1&#djiwaypointv2action_djiwaypointv2actuator_actuatorindex_inline) (*Haven't personally tested it*). 
Additionally, the left camera (gimbal position 1) is used for capturing photos by drones with multiple payloads executing `DJIWaypointMissionV1`.